# DRUPAL, Views, Exposed Search Filter: how to never filter a particular node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using Views on Drupal. I've added the Search exposed filter to search the nodes.

I would like to avoid to filter 1 special node (which is sticky, on the top of the list). In other words, the search filter should ignore that node, and it should be always displayed.

how can I do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider creating a different view for it - that just shows this nod and that's all. Create a block from it and put at the top.

Comment: thanks for reply. Isn't any other method to apply search criterias to only some nodes types ?

Comment: In the view you can define what type of material, you want (don't want) to see in it.

Comment: I want to see both materials (content types), but I don't want to apply a filter to a specific content type

Comment: you can also create a view attachment and place it above the page display. i'd say it would look a lot better than using a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Node : Type filter in the View to exclude specific node types from the results.